# Measure Total in DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, pivot-table, dax

I have a simple data model with two dimensions and a fact table. The dimensions are called BondDim and AccountDim. They slice the fact table. The BondDim and AccountDim join to the fact table in a one-to-many relationship. I would like to create the measure "BondAmt" as shown here in bold outline:

[image]

I have tried this measure, but it seems to cross-join Bond and Account, and blows up the pivot table with a lot of blank rows:

```
=calculate([Amt], ALL(AccountDim), BondDim[Bond] = BondDim[Bond] )
```

How can I calculate the BondAmt totals column and have it be correct in whatever Bond and Account filter context I have?

EDIT:

As suggested by @sergiom, using

```
BondAmt = CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Amt]), ALL(AccountDim))
```

returns the following:

[image]

It returns all of the accounts regardless of whether the Account owns the Bond (Bond #1 shown in the picture). How can I return only those accounts that have Amt in the bond?

Comment: Please include the relationships between the tables

Comment: what is the PortDim that appears in your DAX code and isn't mentioned in the question description?

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately I am using excel 2016 and I don’t have REMOVEFILTERS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to remove the filter over AccountDim, since the existing filter over BondDim is not to be changed, like

```
BondAmt = CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Amt]), ALL(AccountDim))
```

Edit:
to avoid the rows with Accounts that don't own the bond we must add a test to check that the combination of Bond and Account is present in the fact table

```
BondAmt = 
IF (
    NOT ISEMPTY(Fact),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Fact[Amt] ),
        ALL ( AccountDim )
    )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using excel 2016 and I don’t have the REMOVEFILTERS function.

Comment: No big deal, REMOVEFILTERS is just syntactic sugar for ALL

Comment: This gets me the right number, but returns every Account regardless of whether it owns the Bond or not. See the short edit in the question. Any way I can return only those accounts that own Bond #1 (Amt is not blank)?

Comment: I edited the answer adding a test on the existence of a row with the current combination of Bond and Account

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I needed.